# What is the difference between size and capacity in lshw?

Tags: linux, disk, lshw

I just came across an odd thing while looking at my disks with `lshw`. I have a 4 TB and a 6 TB disk. `lshw` shows the expected 6 TB for size but nearly 8 TB for capacity. The 4 TB disk has the same values on both properties:

```
  *-disk:1
       product: HUS726060AL5210
       size: 5589GiB (6001GB)
       capacity: 7231GiB (7764GB)
  *-disk:2
       product: HGST HUS724040AL
       size: 3726GiB (4TB)
       capacity: 3726GiB (4TB)
```

Where does the difference come from for the 6 TB disk? Is the additional space somehow usable?

Comment: What does `hdparm -I` (capital ‘i’) report for the 6TB drive?

Comment: @StephenKitt It only reports `SG_IO: bad/missing sense data` and `HDIO_DRIVE_CMD(identify) failed: Input/output error`. I get output for the 4 TB disk.